# Remove all Null values from Sql table at once

Tags: teradata, isnull

I am very new to Teradata and SQL environment. I am trying to remove all the null values from sql table in teradata using
ISNULL(COLUMNNAME,0). But it gives an error that "the data type does not match the defined data type name". Also, would like to know if there is any way of removing all NULL at once rather than column wise writing the above query again and again.

Comment: maybe this column is not numeric (string, datetime, etc...)? if so use proper value in 2nd parameter (empty string, valid datetime literal, etc.).

Comment: Sounds like a type clash between the integer 0 that you provided as a null replacement and some other type columns such as strings. Just curious- Why do you want to replace all nulls with a 0?

Comment: Thanks Akina and SQLRaptor. I need to aggregate the fields later and having null values  creates extra rows. Just a query, if i use '0' instead of 0, would aggregation functions treat it as integer?

Comment: One key thing to remember for your dataset 0 may have a completely different meaning then NULL so changing any values to add one where it isn't present may give you bad results.

Comment: @KuljeetKeshav Aggregate functions ignore NULL values, except for COUNT(*). Use COUNT(Expression) to count and ignore nulls. I would be very careful with making such a change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no function named `ISNULL` in Teradata/Standard SQL, it's called `COALESCE` instead:

```
COALESCE(columnname, 0)
```

And it has to be applied to each column individually.

Comment: ZEROIFNULL(COLNAME) can also be used to substitute 0 in  place of null.

Comment: @KuljeetKeshav: Of course, but that's non-Standard, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do. ISNULL(COLUMNNAME,0) is a function that returns 0 if COLUMNNAME contains a null (it does not change anything in the table, you will have to do an update to modify the table).

The error message you get is likely because COLUMNNAME is a different type than a number. If COLUMNNAME is of type string you can use:

```
ISNULL(COLUMNNAME, '')
```

if it's of type date you need a date:

```
ISNULL(COLUMNNAME, DATE('1900-01-01') ) -- I just invented one here, use one that makes sense in your context
```

and so forth. As you noted, applying a function to a column does an implicit rename of the resulting column. Most DBMS generates a rather cryptic name so it makes sense to do an explicit rename as in:

```
ISNULL(COLUMNNAME, '') AS COLUMNNAME
```

if you want to preserve the name.

Comment: Thanks Lennart! I think I got my mistake. I need to use something like < select Isnull(a.Columnname, ' ') as Columnname > to make it work.

Comment: That's probably correct. Applying a function to a column will do an implicit rename of the resulting column. Most DBMS will generate a cryptic name, so it almost always makes sense to explicitly rename the column as you do. I'll add some info about that to my answer.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to replace all nulls to 0 (or blank), say for all columns belonging to one data type?

Comment: You will have to apply one function per column, there's no way around that. You might want to create a view that does the transformation for you, and then select from the view.